# Uncaught ImagickException: UnableToOpenBlob 'uploads/Datapath.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3315

Tags: php, imagick

I am trying to use ImageMagick to covert the first page of pdf to image but it is not working, I tried all the solutions from Stack Overflow and some other websites such as using real path but none is working.

```
<?php
$image=new Imagick();
$image->readImage('uploads/Datapath.pdf[0]');
$image->writeImages('uploads/ima.jpg');
?>
```

This is the code but not working and is giving error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: UnableToOpenBlob 'uploads/Datapath.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3315 in F:\xampp\htdocs\Web_Engineering\webproj\try.php:3 Stack trace: #0 F:\xampp\htdocs\Web_Engineering\webproj\try.php(3): Imagick->readImage('uploads/Datapat...') #1 {main} thrown in F:\xampp\htdocs\Web_Engineering\webproj\try.php on line 3
```

Comment: The error message is quite self-explanatory. Do you have a `uploads` folder with a file called `Datapath.pdf` (btw: what's the `[0]` thing?) in `F:\xampp\htdocs\Web_Engineering\webproj`? Notice you're giving `readImage` a relative path so you're essentially looking for this path: `F:\xampp\htdocs\Web_Engineering\webproj\uploads\Datapath.pdf`.

Comment: yes I do have uploads folder and datapath.pdf and I saw [0] is used to tell just to read first page. Btw i tried without [0] too.